# Create custom SELinux domain using magiskpolicy

Tags: magisk, selinux

Tried to make custom domain for an app that is installed from PlayStore. I created a module that would patch the policy at boot and edited **system/etc/selinux/plat_seapp_contexts** to assign the app my new domain.

**sepolicy.rule** file:

```
type battery_app appdomain
allow battery_app sysfs * *
```

I also added this line of code to **plat_seapp_contexts**:

```
user=_app seinfo=platform name=com.someapp domain=battery_app type=app_data_file levelFrom=all
```

After running **ps -eZ | grep com.someapp** the app is still running in **untrusted_app** domain. I don't know what i did wrong.